# Enforcing that subclasses have factory method

Tags: dart

Is there a way to ensure every subclass of the `AbstractClass` has a `factory` method.

I want to make sure each concrete class has a `fromJSON` method which creates a class from JSON.

```
abstract class AbstractClass {

}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
  String sample;

  ConcreteClass(sample);

  factory ConcreteClass.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ConcreteClass(json['sample']);
  }
}
```

Comment: What would be the advantage if there were a way? Dart doesn't allow to call constructors or static methods on Type instances, so even if Dart would allow to enforce that, you couldn't take advantage. You could write a script yourself that checks such constraints similar to Dart codegen solutions do it to gain information what code to generate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to enforce any static members or constructors in subclasses in Dart.